# Best way to get the nth element of each tuple from a list of tuples in Python

Tags: python

I had some code that contained `zip(*G)[0]` (and elsewhere, `zip(*G)[1]`, with a different G).  `G` is a list of tuples.  What this does is return a list of the first (or generally, for `zip(*G)[n]`, the `n-1`th) element of each tuple in G as a tuple.  For example,

```
>>> G = [(1, 2, 3), ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('you', 'and', 'me')]
>>> zip(*G)[0]
(1, 'a', 'you')
>>> zip(*G)[1]
(2, 'b', 'and')
```

This is pretty clever and all, but the problem is that it doesn't work in Python 3, because `zip` is an iterator there.  Furthermore, 2to3 isn't smart enough to fix it.  So the obvious solution is to use `list(zip(*G))[0]`, but that got me thinking: there is probably a more efficient way to do this.  There is no need to create all the tuples that zip creates.  I just need the `n`th element of each tuple in G.

Is there are more efficient, but equally compact way to do this?  I'm OK with anything from the standard library.  In my use case, each tuple in G will be at least length `n`, so there is no need to worry about the case of zip stopping at the smallest length tuple (i.e., `zip(*G)[n]` will always be defined).

If not, I guess I'll just stick with wrapping the `zip` in `list()`.

(P.S., I know this is unnecessary optimization.  I'm just curious is all)

**UPDATE:**

In case anyone cares, I went with the `t0, t1, t2 = zip(*G)` option.  First, this lets me give meaningful names to the data. My `G` actually consists of length 2 tuples (representing numerators and denominators).  A list comprehension would only be marginally more readable than the zip, but this way is much better (and since in most cases the zip was list I was iterating through in a list comprehension, this makes things flatter).

Second, as noted by @thewolf and @Sven Marnach's excellent answers, this way is faster for smaller lists.  My G is actually not large in most cases (and if it is large, then this definitely won't be the bottleneck of the code!).

But there were more ways to do this than I expected, including the new `a, *b, c = G` feature of Python 3 I didn't even know about.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

At least the *fastest* way in Python 2.7 is

```
t0,t1,t2=zip(*G) for SMALLER lists and [x[0] for x in G] in general
```

Here is the test:

```
from operator import itemgetter

G = [(1, 2, 3), ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('you', 'and', 'me')]

def f1():
   return tuple(x[0] for x in G)

def f2():
   return tuple(map(itemgetter(0), G))

def f3():
    return tuple(x for x, y, z in G)     

def f4():
    return tuple(list(zip(*G))[0])

def f5():
    t0,*the_rest=zip(*G)
    return t0

def f6():
    t0,t1,t2=zip(*G)
    return t0                

cmpthese.cmpthese([f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6],c=100000)
```

Results:

```
    rate/sec     f4     f5     f1     f2     f3     f6
f4   494,220     -- -21.9% -24.1% -24.3% -26.6% -67.6%
f5   632,623  28.0%     --  -2.9%  -3.0%  -6.0% -58.6%
f1   651,190  31.8%   2.9%     --  -0.2%  -3.2% -57.3%
f2   652,457  32.0%   3.1%   0.2%     --  -3.0% -57.3%
f3   672,907  36.2%   6.4%   3.3%   3.1%     -- -55.9%
f6 1,526,645 208.9% 141.3% 134.4% 134.0% 126.9%     --
```

If you don't care if the result is a list, a list comprehension if faster.

Here is a more extended benchmark with variable list sizes:

```
from operator import itemgetter
import time
import timeit 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f1():
   return [x[0] for x in G]

def f1t():
   return tuple([x[0] for x in G])

def f2():
   return tuple([x for x in map(itemgetter(0), G)])

def f3():
    return tuple([x for x, y, z in G])    

def f4():
    return tuple(list(zip(*G))[0])

def f6():
    t0,t1,t2=zip(*G)
    return t0     

n=100    
r=(5,35)
results={f1:[],f1t:[],f2:[],f3:[],f4:[],f6:[]}    
for c in range(*r):
    G=[range(3) for i in range(c)] 
    for f in results.keys():
        t=timeit.timeit(f,number=n)
        results[f].append(float(n)/t)

for f,res in sorted(results.items(),key=itemgetter(1),reverse=True):
    if f.__name__ in ['f6','f1','f1t']:
        plt.plot(res, label=f.__name__,linewidth=2.5)
    else:    
        plt.plot(res, label=f.__name__,linewidth=.5)

plt.ylabel('rate/sec')
plt.xlabel('data size => {}'.format(r))  
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

Which produces this plot for smaller data sizes (5 to 35):

[image: smaller]

And this output for larger ranges (25 to 250):

[image: larger]

You can see that `f1`, a list comprehension is fastest. `f6` and `f1t` trading places as the fastest to return a tuple.

Comment: I'm not familiar with cmpthese.  How should I interpret the results?

Comment: @asmeurer: `cmpthese` prints a Perl style performance comparison. It is based on Python's `timeit` module. It just runs all the subroutines and compares the speed. The table is printed slowest on top to fastest on the bottom. The faster the rate / sec, the faster the subroutine. The table to the right shows how much faster: f6 is 208.9% faster than f4; f3 is 3.1% faster than f2 but 55.9% slower than f6 and so on. You read it from the left and it shows how much faster / slower each is in comparison to each other.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer for now.  I'm quite surprised that f6 is the fastest.  Maybe you should test with a larger G.  Anyhow, this will also make my list comprehensions where I tend to have the `zip(*G)` a little easier to read, as it will split part of it into a separate line.

Comment: I also just noticed that in at least one place I am using `zip(*G)[0]` and `zip(*G)[1]` for the same G.  So this way will clearly be the best for that.

Comment: This comparison has a few issues: 1. The test data set is far too small for any meaningful results.  If the data is that small, it simply does not matter which variant to use, and details like looking up names from the global namespace bias the results. 2. The benchmark only compares the variants producing tuples.  The only reason the OP used a tuple seems to be that the `zip()` solution happens to give one. 3. As a consequence, it does not include the list comprehensions, which are probably the variants most people would use in practise (and they are pretty fat, too).

Comment: 4. The last code snippet produces a list with a single `map` object in it, and does not iterate `G` at all.

Comment: @Sven Marnach: Don't you need to fix the `map/itemgetter` variation in your answer so it doesn't do the same thing in Python 3K as the last code snippet currently in this answer?

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Yes, you are right about item 4. In fact tho -- even with larger dicts of 3 tuple (regardless whether it is returning a list or tuple) f6 is substantially faster. Try it.

Comment: @martineau: Yes, to measure the time it takes, I would need to change it.  But I'm not measuring the time it takes.  (Moreover, it does not do the exact same thing.  It returns something that can be iterated over in a meaningful way, whereas the function here returns a single-element list.)

Comment: @the wolf: I addressed the points I raised in my own micro-benchmark, and indeed I got quite different results than you – see my answer.  (I also removed the redundant call to `tuple()` in `f4()`, which I missed yesterday.)

Comment: A better name for the y axis is just "rate", not "rate/sec".

Answer (score 18):

You can use a list comprehension

```
[x[0] for x in G]
```

or `operator.itemgetter()`

```
from operator import itemgetter
map(itemgetter(0), G)
```

or sequence unpacking

```
[x for x, y, z in G]
```

**Edit**: Here is my take on timing the different options, also in Python 3.2:

```
from operator import itemgetter
import timeit

G = list(zip(*[iter(range(30000))] * 3))

def f1():
    return [x[0] for x in G]
def f2():
    return list(map(itemgetter(0), G))
def f3():
    return [x for x, y, z in G]
def f4():
    return list(zip(*G))[0]
def f5():
    c0, *rest = zip(*G)
    return c0
def f6():
    c0, c1, c2 = zip(*G)
    return c0
def f7():
    return next(zip(*G))

for f in f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7:
    print(f.__name__, timeit.timeit(f, number=1000))
```

Results on my machine:

```
f1 0.6753780841827393
f2 0.8274149894714355
f3 0.5576457977294922
f4 0.7980241775512695
f5 0.7952430248260498
f6 0.7965989112854004
f7 0.5748469829559326
```

Comments:

1. I used a list with 10000 triples to measure the actual processing time, and make function call overhead, name lookups etc. negligible, which would otherwise seriously influence the results.
2. The functions return a list or a tuple – whatever is more convenient for the particular solution.
3. Compared to [the wolf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12442775/279627), I removed the redundant call to `tuple()` from `f4()` (the result of the expression is a tuple already), and I added a function `f7()` which only works to extract the first column.

As expected, the list comprehensions are fastest, together with the somewhat less general `f7()`.

**Another edit**: Here are the results for ten columns instead of three, with the code adapted where appropriate:

```
f1 0.7429649829864502
f2 0.881648063659668
f3 1.234360933303833
f4 1.92038893699646
f5 1.9218590259552002
f6 1.9172680377960205
f7 0.6230220794677734
```

Comment: I vote for the first one as the best way. There's no need to create dummy variables, or use some (to me strange and overly complicated) operators and maps.

Comment: @martineau: I'd usually go with the first one.  In some situations, I prefer the last one, e.g. when iterating over a list of heterogeneous tuples, because I can document the field names of the tuples by using matching loop variable names.

Comment: Interesting how your timing results differ so much from @the wolf's. I can see how you measured things and it looks sound. Any idea why his are so different, esp for `f6()`?

Comment: @martineau: The main reason is that the input data set was too small.  In the wolf's answer, the overhead of name lookups etc is significant.  You would get quite different results with optimisations like importing global names into the local namespace via bogus default parameters etc.  All those things won't matter with a big data set, since they are completely dominated by the actual processing time.

Answer (score 6):

A very clever **Python 3 only** way is with starred assignments or [extended iterable unpacking](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/):

```
>>> G = [(1, 2, 3), ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('you', 'and', 'me')]
>>> items_I_want,*the_rest=zip(*G)
>>> items_I_want
(1, 'a', 'you')
>>> the_rest
[(2, 'b', 'and'), (3, 'c', 'me')]
```

Since you are writing code for both, you could use explicit unpacking (which works on Python 2 and Python 3):

```
>>> z1,z2,z3=zip(*G)
>>> z1
(1, 'a', 'you')
>>> z2
(2, 'b', 'and')
>>> z3
(3, 'c', 'me')
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Starred assignments are unique in Py3 and the closest to the OP's code?

Comment: That's pretty cool! And it even works in list comprehensions: `[j for j, *_ in [(1, 2, 3), ('a', 'b', 'c')]]` -> `[1, 'a']`.  Unfortunately, as I noted, I am writing code in Python 2 and converting it to Python 3.

Comment: @asmeurer: Then use the form of `z1,z2,z3=zip(*G)` which works in both Python 2 and Python 3 and is the fastest.